# Dynamically get DB Column Default Constraint and alter column datatype

Tags: sql-server, database

I am writing a migration script for a customer where some db columns data tape changed.

When I run alter column datatype

```
ALTER TABLE [table]
ALTER COLUMN [column] VARCHAR(8000)
```

I am getting an error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 344
> The object 'DF__table__Domain__2CBDA3B5' is dependent on column 'column'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 344
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because one or more objects access this column.

Then I need to drop the default constraint, and rerun alter table again :

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__TableName__ColumnName__6BAEFA67]
```

So my question is there is can I do better and if there is any way to find default constraint dynamically and pass it to alter column datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way (and easy way) to find out is to use the table designer in ssms, make your change and then, click on "generated change script" on the table designer toolbar.

Look in the script what SSMS is about to do and copy/paste or what you need  (or adapt it) into your own script.

[image]

[image]